# Copy data from MySQL to Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, mariadb, data-migration, bigdata

What is the easiest and fastest way to migrate some tables of my MySQL database to Google BigQuery?

I want something simple like:

`$ migrate <mysql opts> <mysql list of tables> <big query opts>`

Answer (score 2):

shantanuo has on gist a script that can be adapted for your situation and packaged into a single executable

https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/4466298